# Connecting to splunk hosted in azure using splunk sdk in python is giving timeout error

Tags: python, azure, port, splunk, splunk-sdk

**I have my splunk instance hosted azure and i wanted to connect to it via splunkSDK but it is giving timeout error for 8089 port and 443 it is giving connection reset.**

```
import splunklib.client as client
service = client.connect(host='IP-Address', port=8089,
                   username='admin', password='...')
```

I have checked firewall and also tried executing this in azure databricks, still issue is present and HTTPS on 443 is also enabled in azure hosted splunk instance. 
In web browser the ip is accessible via https like.. https://ip-address But http://ip-address:443 is giving no response. Can someone help solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://ip-address:8089 . If its not accessible, you will need to contact Splunk Cloud support and request they enable port 8089 access.

Refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.1/RESTREF/RESTsystem#Splunk_Cloud_URL_for_REST_API_access

## Managed Splunk Cloud deployments

[https://*deployment-name*.splunkcloud.com:8089](https://_deployment-name_.splunkcloud.com:8089)

## Self-service Splunk Cloud deployments

To get the required credentials, submit a support case on the Support Portal. After installing the credentials, use the following URL.

[https://input-*deployment-name*.cloud.splunk.com:8089](https://input-_deployment-name_.cloud.splunk.com:8089)

Comment: Yes, i have tried https:ip-address:8089 it is giving timeout, And the 8089 port is already enabled along with bunch of other ports.

Comment: If its timing out, its most likely that the port hasn't been enabled. Contact Splunk Support Portal